# How to get the data from json in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value from json set when clicking event occur. and that value is stored in one variable and passed to function

html

```
<ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item" id="Driver1">Driver1</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item id="Driver2"">Driver2</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item" id="Driver3">Driver3</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item" id="Driver4">Driver4</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item" id="Driver5">Driver5</li>
            </ul>
```

Jquery

```
var driverLocation={
        "Driver1":"12.98180953,77.44056702",
        "Driver2":"12.89079587,77.35954285",
        "Driver3":"12.81046221,77.44056702",
        "Driver4":"12.85197115,77.74406433",
        "Driver5":"13.17710836,77.8401947"
        }



 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".list-group-item").on("click", function(){
    alert("hi");        
        var selection= $(this).attr('id');
        var location=driverLocation[selection];
        placeMarker(e.location,map)
    });
});
```

It returns  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You should include the jquery. Also, correct the quotes on the second <li> element

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a jquery script tag in your head? If not you will need to add one as jQuery isn't packaged with browsers.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct like below and try

```
<li class="list-group-item id="Driver2"">Driver2</li>
```

to

```
<li class="list-group-item" id="Driver2">Driver2</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add jquery library and ensure correct order.

This is wrong usage:

```
<script src="my.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Should be like this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="my.js"></script>
```